# ACF Save selected value from a select field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a repeater field to populate select field's choises in every user profile using the following code

```
function acf_load_repeater_field_field_choices($field) {
    global $current_user;
    //Get the repeater field values
    $choices = get_field('repeater_field',$current_user);
    $field['choices'] = [];
    // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if (is_array($choices)) {
        foreach ($choices as $choice) {
            //Set the select values
            $field['choices'][$choice['subfield']] = $choice['subfield'];
        }
    }
    // return the field
    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=select_field', 'acf_load_repeater_field_field_choices');
```

After populating the repeater field I'm displaying the select field in a form and save the selected value with the following code but it seems that it doesn't save the selected value

```
$field = get_field_object('repeater_field_key');
if (!empty($field['choices'])) { ?>
    <select>
        <?php foreach ($field['choices'] as $v => $l) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $v; ?>"><?php echo $l; ?></option>
            <?php $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
            update_field($field, $field['value'], 'user_'.$current_user_id); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible, but lets first forget about the AJAX side. Lets make it a bit more basic:

1. The user selects a post type
2. The user saves the post
3. The user sees the select field populated with repeater values from the post type selected

ُEX:

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field )
{
    // globals
    global $post;
    
    
    // load selected value from post type field
    $p = get_field( 'Field_B', $post->ID );
    
    
    // now load repeater field from selected post object
    if(get_field( 'Field_B', $p->ID ))
    {
        // loop through the repeater and use the sub fields "value" and "label"
        while(has_sub_field('Field_B', $p->ID))
        {
            $value = get_sub_field('value');
            $label = get_sub_field('label');
 
            $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;
        }
    }
    
    return $field;
}

// acf/load_field/name={$field_name} - filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=Field_A', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

This is untested but should work. After you have it working, you can write some AJAX to fetch the values.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how this helps. 
The function for the repeater field is already working and populates the values on a select field. 
The problem is that it doesn't seem to save the selected value on form submission. I don't think that AJAX is necessary here. According to ACF plugin you can save the value on form sumbission with 'update_field'. Maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: can you check `$current_user_id` are it return NO of current user ?

Comment: The $current_user_id works just fine, I believe the problem is here 'update_field($field, $field['value'], 'user_'.$current_user_id);'

Comment: try : `update_sub_field( array( $field_key, $row, $sub_field ), $new_value, $post_id );`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Thank you for your effort though.

Comment: can you debug your code ?

Comment: As you can see here these are the values in the repeater field https://prnt.sc/XjSQtv-ajh5- and this is the select field with these values that populated by the repeater field https://prnt.sc/bEqFoEI7H1ub . So this is working just fine. What it does not work for sure is the update_field code. It returns null on database https://prnt.sc/bc6-l1Gbyx4x

Comment: try this code  `update_post_meta( $current_user_id,$field , $field['value'] );`

Comment: Still nothing... Returns null